# What is the idiomatic way to include data in error messages?

Tags: string, go, error-handling

I’ve encountered different ways to incorporate variables into error messages in Go. In the following example, which way is the idiomatic one? Is there a better alternative?

Which is safer when things start to break? For example, when there is very little memory left available, the option that allocates fewer bytes would be preferable.

Which is faster, in case we need to generate a lot of errors?

The full runnable code can be seen in the [Go Play Space](https://goplay.space/#_jQXIj6hZq) or in the official [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_jQXIj6hZq).

```
func f() error {
    return SepError("Sepuled " + strconv.Itoa(n) + " sepulcas " + strconv.Itoa(t) +
        " times each")
}

func g() error {
    return SepError(strings.Join([]string{
        "Sepuled", strconv.Itoa(n), "sepulcas", strconv.Itoa(t), "times each"}, " "))
}

func h() error {
    return SepError(fmt.Sprintf("Sepuled %d sepulcas %d times each", n, t))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have very little memory, or are going to be generating a HUGE amount of these errors I wouldn't worry about it.  As far as idiomatic Go, I would opt for the `h()` option because it is easier to read.

The nice thing here is that allocations, memory used, and speed can be tested with some simple benchmarks

```
func BenchmarkF(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i <= b.N; i++ {
        f()
    }
}

func BenchmarkG(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i <= b.N; i++ {
        g()
    }
}

func BenchmarkH(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i <= b.N; i++ {
        h()
    }
}
```

Output of `go test -bench . -benchmem

```
BenchmarkF-8    10000000           169 ns/op          72 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkG-8    10000000           204 ns/op         120 B/op          5 allocs/op
BenchmarkH-8     5000000           237 ns/op          80 B/op          4 allocs/op
```

As you can see, `f()` is the fastest, uses the least memory, and is tied for the fewest allocations.  It is also, not worth (in my opinion) the additional cost of readability.